# Что такое "алле"?

Tags: этимология

В процессе написания вопроса о собачьих командах возник еще один вопрос. Все знают возглас циркачей "алле". Есть даже понятие "парад алле" (точно не знаю, что это, ибо цирк не люблю).
Интересно было бы узнать, имеет ли это слово какой-то смысл, кроме возгласа-команды, и родственно ли оно "телефонному" слову "алло", которое, если мне не изменяет память, имеет греческое происхождение?

Comment: @hanyo. Смею Вам заметить, уважаемый (или уважаемая) HANYO, что если Вы не любите цирк, то это, разумеется, ваше сугубо личное дело. Но уважать чужой труд, в том числе и труд цирковых АРТИСТОВ (а это труд тяжелейший), Вы всё-таки обязаны! И выглядит очень некультурно с вашей стороны (да, и не только с вашей) называть АРТИСТОВ ЦИРКА банально-пренебрежительным словом словом "ЦИРКАЧИ".

Answer (score 2):

слово алЁ  от английского здравствуйте - HЕLLO, то в свою очередь от немецкого Heil (хайль), от датского Hej, а то в свою очередь от русского эй. На западе принято нынче просто хай, видимо в пику нацистам после второй мировой войны. Почему от русских, отдельный вопрос.

Алле в фразе Парад-Алле, от Французского  идти. Alle. ПАРАД идет. Парад от датского PAARD-лошадь + по умолчанию французское pas - па --шаг. Хотя особенной уверенности нет.
Дело в том, что есть слово PARADIS - рай, конечное место.
От него и Фасмеровская этимология.

Парад

парад пара́д род. п. -а, пара́дное ме́сто, начиная с Петра I; см. Смирнов 217. Через франц. раrаdе из исп. раrаdа "остановка, (местопребывание", раrаr "задерживать" (Гамильшег, ЕW 668). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973.

Но у нас есть слово рад, и порадоваться, а парад известное дело -- увеселение.
так что похоже вернулось к нам почти неискаженным.

Кстати, хеллоуин от здравствуй, зима.

Comment: @fatyalink.В вашем ответе верно то, что АЛЛЕ это от французского ИДТИ. Что такое цирковой парад-алле? Это когда весь коллектив артистов программы выходит в манеж, прощаясь со зрителями, - т.е. артисты ИДУТ (alle). Я некоторое время работал в цирке (в обслуживающем персонале). Есть также и цирковая команда/восклицание: алле-ап! Это означает типа иди-вверх или иди-вперёд. Как команду алле-ап произносят дрессировщики своим животным. Но бывает, что артисты подбадривающе восклицают это самим себе перед тем, как выйти из форгана в манеж, - слышал такое неоднократно. Тут не Хелло/Хайль.